# What is the easiest way to level up my profile?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

While there's tons of badges out there, collecting cards and cards takes a lot of time, and only results in a 100 xp badge, is there anything other than just crafting badges that would help increase more exp?

Are there games that have extremely few cards to collect? Or is there an easier way to level up my profile?

Comment: The [Steam Trading Card page](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/) seems to state that crafting badges is _the_ way to gain EXP.

Comment: But that's not true. You can own games to get exp, you can do Steam Community related tasks to get exp, there's more than just doing that, isn't it?

Comment: Questions like these show one thing. Gamification works.

Comment: @Retrosaur: Oh yeah, I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're looking for games with as little cards as possible, the following *incomplete* list shows games which only have five cards each:

- Don't Starve
- Super Meat Boy
- The Swapper
- DLC Quest
- Trine 2
- Bastion
- The Walking Dead
- Bleed
- Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
- Defy Gravity

for a probably complete list of games with trading cards, have a look at [this one](http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?showcase)

*Costs: With a current card price of ~.2$ per card, that's about 1$/badge, so 100XP for 1$. Due to the level limit you cannot do this forever with the same game though*

---

Other ways to obtain XP are:

- "Years of service" I got 250 XP for five years, so I guess it's 50 XP per year. *Costs: time*
- "Community leader" *(Max: Lvl 3)* Just do 28/29 of the stuff mentioned there (post a screenshot, trade, link to facebooke etc). *Costs: Data*
- "Director of Acquisitions" some XP per game you own (1-5 XP/game, see [here](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/1/864971660995835491/) as per [Nolonar's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124996/88)). I don't know how DLCs count here, and the scaling is probably non-linear. *Costs: a lot - even with an optimistic 10$/game you have to spend about 1000$ for another 100XP once you have many games*
- "Steam Summer/Holiday Sale 201X; Potato Sack; Trading Card Beta Tester": XP based on the achievements/participation. *Costs: A time machine...*

So in summary, apart from the up to 200 XP from the "Pillar of community" badges the most promising source of XP are indeed gamecard badges. The badges with fewer gamecards are probably easier to obtain, but then again they may also be more expensive on the market.

Comment: I just finished my 14th task (out of 26) for the *Pillar of Community* badge and got the level 1 badge & 100 XP, so +1 for teaching me, that it **does** award XP :D

Comment: You're welcome. 14th it is? Ok, next one's at 22 so I assume there's a third one for the complete 26

Comment: @Zommuter There is no level for 26. Just 2 levels.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Thanks for clarifying, I didn't complete the 22 for the second to see that and merely guessed

Comment: Optimistic 10$/game? My average is around 3-4$.

Comment: @UncleZeiv YMMV...

Comment: Other games with five cards: Worms Revolution, CS: GO

Comment: Keep in mind that prices float alot. 
Don't starve whole deck for example is worth like 1.40 USD
Where The Swapper is worth like 2.40 USD

Comment: [**This website**](http://steam.tools/cards/) gives a a lot of informations about all of steam cards : number of cards in a set, individual price, set's price, your current lvl in a specific badge, ....

Answer (score 5):

By far the **easiest** way, is to do nothing.
You get **50 XP** per year since your registration.

By far the **fastest** way, is to buy games with trading cards as well as their cards.
For every game owned, you get a few extra XP; For more information on how many games award how much XP, [read here](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/1/864971660995835491/).
Trading card badges awards **100 XP** each. You can only gather half of the cards available per game, unless you receive a booster pack. For the rest, you have to trade.

Comment: Very well, then +1 for the XP/game link. I guess we can clean up some comments

Answer (score 2):

This is my little strategy to farm some XP and Boosters.

-Buy low priced games from Bundles and sales. Like Humble Bundle (~5 games for 1$ minimum). 
Look up if there are any games with trading cards first, in case you're not interested in the games themselves.

-Look for games that needs like only 5 cards to make a badge. 
That way you don't need to put much money into buying the cards that are left. And you can also sell your other cards for games that need like 15 cards to make a badge. In that way you will level pretty fast.

-Get eligible for as many games you can for a higher chance to get booster packs.
I'm currently eligible for ~25 games and I have maybe ~50 trading card games left to farm.

-Buying games from bundles etc is a good, cheap and pretty fast way to lvl up since you get xp for every game you buy/own. And if you love playing games like me it's another bonus for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can buy steam cards for games at the community market...
These cards can still be used in the badge collection.
Most cards I see are around 15 cents, some games cheaper and some games More expensive

Comment: Though your answer explain how to gain XP on your steam profile, the Asker wanted another way than crafting badges with cards

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the fastest way is by participating in sales to get badges, buying games to get xp, getting 50 xp per year since registration, and buying cards in the market to craft badges. I would recommend for you to badge up on cards from games that have relatively small collections, a lot of people play, and thus have cheaper prices. Example: Castle Crashers.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest badges are:

- Community Ambassador(200XP),which is made by completing community tasks.
- Gem maker(100XP),Buy a cheap loading screen or emoticon of 0.03$ and convert it     into gems.
- Participating in sale events(100-200XP).
- Years of service(1year=50XP).
- None of the above works for a limited account, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Another great way of getting easy badges is to play on some F2P games (that have trading cards), and then either complete the badges for the game or selling the cards you get with the game on the Market and buying any cards with the money you got for any sets you need to complete. Costs: *effort.*

F2P games with Trading Cards include:

- Team Fortress 2
- Strife
- Dota 2
- Warframe
- Dead Island: Epidemic
- Quake Live
- Loadout

Comment: As far as Dota is concerned, the number of trading cards you get is directly related to the money you have spent in the game.  No money spent?  No cards.  I strongly suspect it works the same for most (if not all) of the other games mentioned.

Comment: @JohntheGreen Interestingly enough, you can still get cards from F2P games without spending a cent; that's how it works for all games.

Comment: @kappagasm That's not how it works for all games.  Some, maybe, but not Dota.  I have around 2k hours in Dota and don't have a single card because I haven't ever spent any money on Dota.

Comment: ["Free to play games drop game cards based on your in-game purchasing. For every $9 USD spent (approximate) since the start of the Steam Trading Card Beta, you will earn one card drop."](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq/) ~Steam Community Trading Cards FAQ  cc @kappagasm

Comment: @JohntheGreen Just like TF2 does for my alts, even without buying items you start out at a small amount of max card drops.